# How to assign an object from column values in Google Sheet?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, arrow-functions

I have a google sheet with some data in a single column.
How to assign these values to new object like `{'value[0]':value[0], 'value[1]':value[1],..., 'value[i]':value[i]}`?

I wrote this script, but it assigns pair from last value of `names` only:

```
function getIngredientsList() {
  const url = "SPREADSHEET_URL";
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(url);
  const ws = ss.getSheetByName('Base');
  const names = ws.getRange(2, 3, ws.getLastRow() - 1).getValues().map(a => a[0]);
  let nameList;
  for (let i = 0; i < names.length; i++){
    if (names[i] !== ""){
      let name = {[names[i]]:names[i]};
      nameList = Object.assign(name);
    }    
  } 
  return nameList;
}
```

Where I'm wrong and how to fix it?

Comment: can you share your dummy data with expected output?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe your goal as follows.

- You want to retrieve the values from the cells "C2:C28", and want to create an object that the key and value are the same.

For this, how about this modification? The arguments of `Object.assign()` is `Object.assign(target, ...sources)`. So in your script, `nameList` of `let nameList = {}` is required to be used like `nameList = Object.assign(nameList, name)`.

#### From:

```
let nameList;
for (let i = 0; i < names.length; i++){
  if (names[i] !== ""){
    let name = {[names[i]]:names[i]};
    nameList = Object.assign(name);
  }    
}
```

#### To:

```
let nameList = {};  // Modified
for (let i = 0; i < names.length; i++){
  if (names[i] !== ""){
    let name = {[names[i]]:names[i]};
    nameList = Object.assign(nameList, name);  // Modified
  }
}
```

Or, as other pattern, when `reduce` is used, the following script can also return the same value with above modified script.

```
const nameList = ws.getRange(2, 3, ws.getLastRow() - 1).getValues()
.reduce((o, [e]) => {
  if (e != "") Object.assign(o, {[e]: e});
  return o;
}, {});
```

#### Reference:

- [Object.assign()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign)

Answer (score 2):

More cleaner way to do that is using `reduce` method:

```js
var names = ['ABC', 'XYZ', 'PQR'];
var result = names.reduce((acc, elem)=>{
    acc[elem] = elem;
    return acc;
},{});

console.log(result);
```